# Blank emails Can't retrieve entity config: admin/permission_block

Tags: php, email, magento

I am getting blank shipment emails. If I remove the call to the track.phtml file from the email template the emails are otherwise okay. The track.phtml file and the email templates are default. I am getting an error in the exception log as below. Can anyone help please?

I am getting this error in the exception log

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Can't retrieve entity config:     admin/permission_block' in /home/woods/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(30680): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
#1 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12396): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('admin/permissio...')
#2 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(12359): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable('permission_bloc...')
#3 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32634): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getMainTable()
#4 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32671): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getMainTable()
#5 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(32614): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_initSelect()
#6 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24498): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#7 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(24530): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('admin_resource/...', Array)
#8 /home/woods/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('admin/block_col...', Array)
#9 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Admin_Model_Block.php(79): Mage::getResourceModel('admin/block_col...')
#10 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27659): Mage_Admin_Model_Block->isTypeAllowed('core/template')
#11 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#12 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27322): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#13 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28041): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('{{template conf...')
#14 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(311): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('{{template conf...')
#15 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getProcessedTemplate(Array, true)
#16 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#17 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('40', 'general', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#18 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment.php(462): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#19 /home/woods/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php(222): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment->sendEmail(true, '')
#20 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14272): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController->saveAction()
#21 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18736): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#22 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18266): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /home/woods/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21117): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /home/woods/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /home/woods/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

Comment: Added tags, removed duplicate trace

Answer (score 0):

Error may be related to Block Permission issue. You need to allowed `core/template` block from backend.

For this follow the below steps:

1. Login in backend.
2. From Top Navigation got to `System` >> `Permissions` >> `Blocks`
3. here you need to add `core/template` block and set Is Allowed to `Yes`

Comment: Thanks for that. 

Unfortunately this page gives an error - the blue screen. I have checked in the database and the blocks permissions table has been created and the core/template block is added. I am also getting an error with cms pages where calls to cms blocks or phtml files are not working. I suspect all three are related.     

I have installed the patch 6788 and the above are typically issues from installing the patch according to other posts, but the patch seemed to install correctly and until recently all was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92281/upgrade-from-ce-1-9-1-to-1-9-2-2-produces-cant-retrieve-entity-config-admin-p)

I had this same problem, these steps solved it:

1- Make sure your tmp folder is writable, I had a custom tmp folder set on `lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php`

`'cache_dir' => 'tmp',`

2- Remove var/cache and reload the admin page